Swagger UI failed to serialize object with Minimal API .NET 8
I setup Minimal API with .NET 8 and enable Swagger and Swagger UI.
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.ConfigureHttpJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.SerializerOptions.TypeInfoResolverChain.Insert(0, AppJsonSerializerContext.Default);
});

builder.Services.AddSingleton<DomainDatasEndpoint>();
//
// Enable Swagger
//
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c => 
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Some API", Version = "v1" });
});
var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseCors();
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(options => // UseSwaggerUI is called only in Development.
    {
        options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "v1");
        options.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
    });
}


app.MapPost("/",
    async ([FromBody] DomainData domainData, [FromServices] DomainDatasEndpoint dataEndpoint)
    => await dataEndPoint.AddOrUpdateAsync(domainData));

[JsonSerializable(typeof(DomainData))]
internal partial class AppJsonSerializerContext : JsonSerializerContext
{
}

The API seems to work just fine after I added AppJsonSerializerContext however when I launch Swagger and Swagger kept throwing exception.
Content root path: C:\Projects\TestProjects
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGeneratorException: Failed to generate Operation for action - HTTP: POST api/domaindata/. See inner exception
---> Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGeneratorException: Failed to generate schema for type - NS.Models.DomainData. See inner exception
---> System.NotSupportedException: JsonTypeInfo metadata for type 'NS.Models.Interfaces.DataTypeCode' was not provided by TypeInfoResolver of type '[]'. If using source generation, ensure that all root types passed to the serializer have been annotated with 'JsonSerializableAttribute', along with any types that might be serialized polymorphically.
at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowNotSupportedException_NoMetadataForType(Type type, IJsonTypeInfoResolver resolver)
NS.Models.Interfaces.DataTypeCode is just an Enum
I even configure use AppJsonSerializerContext with UseSwaggerUI( options => {} ) but nothing seems to work. Please help.
Thanks
I have tried this but it does not solve the problem
app.UseSwaggerUI(options => // UseSwaggerUI is called only in Development.
{
    options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "v1");
    options.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
    options.JsonSerializerOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions(JsonSerializerDefaults.Web)
    {
        TypeInfoResolver = AppJsonSerializerContext.Default
    };
});


Why not sharing the code about DomainData so that we could try to reproduce the issue?

I can't produce your issue without a complete sample. I can only deduce that you have codes like this public class DomainDatasEndpoint {public async Task AddOrUpdateAsync(DomainData data) {var a = "1";}} public class DomainData { } public enum DataTypeCode{ TypeA,TypeB,TypeC}, but what is DomainData? and what is DataTypeCode?

The DomainData object contains strings and enum.
I got it working after create new project and migrate the code over. I’m not sure what wrong with the old project. Thanks everyone for attempt to solve the problem
